kria kv260 using lwip tcp/ip perf client in vitis
Im a student, currently developing an application on Vitis using the LWIP 211 TCP/IP perf client on the Xilinx MPSoC Kria KV260 Zynq UltraScale+ in bare-metal. The objective is to enable the board to communicate as a TCP client with a PC acting as a server.
My hardware design consists solely of the Zynq UltraScale+ IP configured with GEM3 (see the picture below : hardware design),
generating the .xsa file that I implemented in Vitis. I started working on the application, and while the Kria KV260 works perfectly as a server, it doesn’t function as a TCP client.
Using Wireshark to monitor the frames, I observed that as a server, there are three frames: SYN, SYN-ACK, and ACK. ( see the picture below: board as a server)
However, as a TCP client, the board sends the SYN frame to the PC that runs a Python script, but the information it carries differs from the server’s frame, and I receive no response from the server (SYN-ACK frame).
The board continues to transmit, but nothing happens. (see the picture below: board as a client)
the picture
My question is: How can I determine if my hardware design is compatible with the LWIP I’m working with, and if it is, how can I make the board function as a TCP client?
thank you.
i want to communicate the boars as a client with the pc as a server using lwip in vitis

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
